# Allow deselection of RadioButton with a ToggleGroup

Tags: javafx, radio-button, togglebutton

I'm trying to get a group of `RadioButton`s in JavaFX 8, with the functionality that at most one can be selected, but it is also possible to remove any selection.

It seems `RadioButton` supports deselection only as long as it has no `ToggleGroup` defined. However, if no `ToggleGroup` is defined more than one `RadioButton` may be selected.

I have tried adding a listener to each button's `onAction` event:

```
for (final RadioButton rb : myRadioButtons) {
    rb.setToggleGroup(myToggleGroup);
    rb.setOnAction(event -> {
        if (rb.isSelected()) {
            myToggleGroup.selectToggle(null);
        }
    });
}
```

However, there are two problems which make this attempt fail - the first is that the `selected` property seems to be updated before the `action` event is fired, so the condition is always true, making it impossible to select *any* button. 
The second problem is that the `action` event is not even fired if the button was selected when it was clicked.

Adding a listener to the `mouseClicked` event isn't any better, as it also fires only after the selected button was changed.

Is there a straightforward way to achieve a group of `RadioButton`s with at-most one selected? Or is the only supported option to handle the `ToggleGroup`'s responsibilities with change listeners etc.?

Comment: [`ToggleButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.html) provides exactly the functionality you are looking for. If you want it to look like a radio button, I guess you could look into using the CSS from RadioButton to customize a toggle button. (Not tested. Might be tricky.)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class RadioButtonTest extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane root = createPane();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Pane createPane() {
        VBox pane = new VBox();
        ToggleGroup tg = new ToggleGroup();
        RadioButton b1 = new RadioButton("one");
        RadioButton b2 = new RadioButton("two");
        tg.getToggles().addAll(b1, b2);

        RadioButtonSelectionHandler b1Selection = new RadioButtonSelectionHandler(b1);
        b1.setOnMousePressed(b1Selection.getMousePressed());
        b1.setOnMouseReleased(b1Selection.getMouseReleased());

        RadioButtonSelectionHandler b2Selection = new RadioButtonSelectionHandler(b2);
        b2.setOnMousePressed(b2Selection.getMousePressed());
        b2.setOnMouseReleased(b2Selection.getMouseReleased());

        pane.getChildren().addAll(b1, b2);
        pane.setPrefHeight(200);
        pane.setPrefWidth(200);
        return pane;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

`RadioButtonSelectionHandler.java`:

```
public class RadioButtonSelectionHandler {

    private boolean selected = false;

    private RadioButton radioButton;

    public RadioButtonSelectionHandler(RadioButton radioButton) {
        this.radioButton = radioButton;
    }

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> mousePressed = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if(radioButton.isSelected())
                selected = true;
        }
    };

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseReleased = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if(selected)
                radioButton.setSelected(false);
            selected = false;
        }
    };

    public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getMousePressed() {
        return mousePressed;
    }

    public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getMouseReleased() {
        return mouseReleased;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**
This solution works but as @James_D suggested it's better to use ToggleButton instead (I hadn't seen his comment before posting this answer). It's not encouraged to use this solution because the functionality you're looking for is not present in [RadioButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/RadioButton.html) by design! It's in [ToggleButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.html).

from JavaDoc:

> Unlike RadioButtons, ToggleButtons in a ToggleGroup do not attempt to
>   force at least one selected ToggleButton in the group. That is, if a
>   ToggleButton is selected, clicking on it will cause it to become
>   unselected. With RadioButton, clicking on the selected button in the
>   group will have no effect.

Comment: I guess it's a solution, but it's clunky. Users are used to clicking a selected option to deselect it.

Comment: I edited my answer. Now you have your functionality without any other Control involved.

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding the UX concerns nor fighting the design (as already mentioned by others), there are two options:

1. subclass RadioButton and override its fire method to revert to the behaviour of ToggleButton
2. dynamically add/remove mouseHandlers to the groups selected toggle

Below is an example for both (not formally tested!). Option one is rather straightforward, option two has some quirks (besides being potentially OS-dependent):

- the eventHandler must be registered as eventFilter
- must consume the event
- selectedToggle of group must be nulled (vs unselecting the toggle)
- must be done on released

The example:

```
public class UnselectableRadioGroup extends Application {
    /**
     * Custom radioBox with behaviour of ToggleButton. 
     */
    public static class MyRadioButton extends RadioButton {

        /**
         * Overridden to revert to ToggleButton behaviour.
         */
        @Override
        public void fire() {
            if (!isDisabled()) {
                setSelected(!isSelected());
                fireEvent(new ActionEvent());
            }
        }

        public MyRadioButton(String text) {
            super(text);
        }

    }

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseHandler;

    private void addListeners(RadioButton nv) {
        if (mouseHandler == null) {
            mouseHandler = e -> {
                e.consume();
                nv.getToggleGroup().selectToggle(null);
            };
        }
        nv.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, mouseHandler);
    }

    private void removeListeners(RadioButton ov) {
        ov.removeEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, mouseHandler);
    }

    private Parent getContent() {
        // dynamic un/register event handlers
        ObservableList<RadioButton> radios = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new RadioButton("one"), new RadioButton("other"), new RadioButton("third")
                );
        ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
        group.getToggles().addAll(radios);

        group.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((src, ov, nv) -> {
            if (ov instanceof RadioButton) {
                removeListeners((RadioButton) ov);
            }
            if (nv instanceof RadioButton) {
                addListeners((RadioButton) nv);
            }
        });

        VBox radioBox = new VBox(10);
        radioBox.getChildren().addAll(radios);

        // RadioButton reverted to ToggleButton
        ObservableList<MyRadioButton> toggles = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new MyRadioButton("one"), new MyRadioButton("other"), new MyRadioButton("third")
                );
        ToggleGroup myGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        myGroup.getToggles().addAll(toggles);
        VBox myRadioBox = new VBox(10);
        myRadioBox.getChildren().addAll(toggles);

        HBox content = new HBox(10, radioBox, myRadioBox);
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane(content);
        return pane;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(getContent());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        //primaryStage.setTitle(FXUtils.version());
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```